# React - beforeunload event on window does not fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
class TradeItemBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log('tradeitembox', props)

    this.removeItemsFromTrade = this.removeItemsFromTrade.bind(this)
    this.onUnloadCleanup = this.onUnloadCleanup.bind(this)
  }


  renderItems() {
    const {trade} = this.props
    if (trade.items.length === 0) {
      return null
    }
    return trade.items.map((item, key) => {
      return <TradeItem key={key} item={item}/>
    })
  }

  onUnloadCleanup() {
    alert('Hello!')
    console.log('unloading')
    if(this.props.trade.items.length > 0) {
      this.removeItemsFromTrade()
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('did mount')
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnloadCleanup)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnloadCleanup)
  }

  removeItemsFromTrade() {
    const {firebase, trade, removeItemFromTrade} = this.props
    trade.items.forEach((item) => {
      item.isTemporarilyInUse = false
      item.currentUser = null
      firebase.set(`/inventory/${item.id}`, item)
      removeItemFromTrade(item.id)
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <Col xs={12} md={5}>
          <div className="items-container">
            {this.renderItems()}
          </div>
          <Button
            onClick={this.removeItemsFromTrade}
            disabled={!this.props.isLoggedIn}
            color="success"
          >
            {'<= Clear trade'}
          </Button>
        </Col>
    )
  }
}

const firebaseWrappedComponent = firebase()(TradeItemBox)

const mapStateToProps = ({trade, user}) => ({
  isLoggedIn: user.isLoggedIn,
  trade
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    removeItemFromTrade
  }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(firebaseWrappedComponent)
```

There is some cleanup I need to do (i.e restore some state to Firebase if the user leaves the page mid-trade), so I read about on SO and found out that I should add an event listener to window.beforeunload in componentDidMount and remove it in componentWillMount. However, the event never fires and the alert never appears, not on refresh nor on tab exit. Any tips as to why this doesn't happen?

Comment: did you see the "did mount" log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return some string from the callback which you assign to this event.

```
onUnloadCleanup() {
        alert('Hello!')
        console.log('unloading')
        if(this.props.trade.items.length > 0) {
          this.removeItemsFromTrade()
        }
        return "unloading";
      }
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

One more question: The event fires on page exit but not on page refresh. Any tips how to handle that?

Comment: add this code before the return value -> e.event.returnValue = "unloading". this should the popup on the screen.